# How do I retrieve user based on session token in the Parse REST API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, session, parse-platform

Using the Parse REST API, once I have authenticated a user with username and password, I get a session token. I store that session token in the user's cookie's, but how do I fetch a user with that session token?

My web app is in Ruby on Rails. I'm using gem parse-ruby-client.

`Parse::User.authenticate('cooldude6', PASSWORD)`

returns

`{"username"=>"cooldude6",
 "createdAt"=>"2013-01-31T15:22:40.339Z",
 "objectId"=>"2bMfWZQ9Ob",
 "sessionToken"=>"zrGuvs3psdndaqswhf0smupsodflkqbFdwRs"}`

How do I then use that sessionToken to retrieve the current user from Parse?

Answer (score 3):

Either query the _User table (endpoint: `/1/users`) for the user with the "cooldude6" username, or get the user directly with its object id (endpoint: `/1/users/2bMfWZQ9Ob`). You'd only use the session token to authenticate REST API requests as the user via the `X-Parse-SessionToken` header, which would let you read and write data based on the user's ACL.

Comment: Thanks Hector! Is there an equivalent to Parse.User.current() for the REST API? I thought I'd be able to use the sessionToken to retrieve that.

Comment: Keeping a local reference to the currentUser is a client side concept, so it doesn't really map well to the REST API.

Comment: It is `X-Parse-Session-Token`. Dash after session is important.

Answer (score 1):

You can validate a session token by making a `GET` request to the [`/1/users/me`](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide/#sessions-retrieving-sessions) endpoint with the token in the `X-Parse-Session-Token` header. I’m unfamiliar with that Ruby gem, but perhaps you could use one of its [User queries](https://github.com/adelevie/parse-ruby-client#retrieving-users)?

However you make the request, Parse will return the full user object if the session token is still valid, or `{"code":101,"error":"invalid session"}` otherwise.